# React-JSS Media Query does not work with chrome mobile emulator

Tags: css, jss

I am using JSS in my React project and I encountered strange issue, which I find hard to solve. Basically I write media query and it is triggered when I shrink my desktop browser. Though while using device toolbar, it does not seem to work. I am trying to hide span when device "width" is smaller than 600px. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
const menuStyles = theme => ({
  flex: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  wrapper: {
    composes: '$flex',
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  span: {
    fontFamily: theme.fontMontserrat,
    marginRight: '30px',
  },
  '@media screen and (max-width: 600px)': {
    span: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, fixed the problem. It was in a completely different part of application.

I forget to add this line in my code:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the generated CSS, if it is what you expect it to be then you have wrong assumptions about CSS/html. At the end, jss does nothing else than generating regular CSS.